# How to get the value of a textbox modified by asp.net ajax from client side(by javascript)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have a textbox in a asp.net update control. When I click a button on the webpage, the value of this textbox got modified. And I want to use javascript to get the modified value. The code I use was:

```
var kmlString = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').getAttribute("value");
```

It only got the original value of my textbox. I am wondering how can I get the latest value of the textbox through javascript. The browsers I intent to use is Firefox and Safari. So it would be great if the script can work for both browsers.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you give us some example? I find it quite hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is the example:
I crate a TextBox(ID=textbox1) in a webpage, it has a default string value, say "Default". When I first open the web page on a browser, the "Default" string appears in the TextBox. Then I click a button on the same web page. This value of this TextBox modified to a new string, say "New Value". The modification is done by a ajax updatepanel in asp.net. After the modification, I want to get the modified value of this TextBox. To achieve that, I tried the code above. But the value it returns is "Default" instead of "New Value".

Comment: And my question is how to get the "New Value" instead of the original unchanged one? Hope I explain it clearly.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
var kmlString = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it still gets the original unmodified value of the Textbox.

Answer (score 0):

congrates! i have got the solution it was a read only field that was causing challenge
remove it from source and add the attribute
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
in page load

may god bless you!